# how to show wp page/post author name in ionic 2 app?

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework

By using ..../wp/v2/pages/ ... wp/v2/posts/ I am able to show post/page title(item.title.rendered).But the author name or publish date can't show by (item.author.rendered) or (item.date.rendered) .

Answer (score 0):

fetch the author id and then use [/wp/v2/users/id](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/users/)

Comment: wp-json/wp/v2/users/id ....its show Forbidden  Page ..403 Forbidden error

Comment: Have you try adding your username and password to the header? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762